# Issue with auto-layout on first launch within UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with four screens in it, of type "BaseViewController" which is a very simple subclass of `UIViewController` that will contain a header displaying a `UILabel` that signifies what screen the user is on. For example, when the user clicks the home tab on the `tabBar`, the label will read "HOME"

Code for `BaseViewController`:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    let screenIndicationLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.setAttrs(font: "bold", size: 25.0, color: .black)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(screenIndicationLabel)
        screenIndicationLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        screenIndicationLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        screenIndicationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        screenIndicationLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Code for the `UITabBarController`:

```
class MainTabController: UITabBarController {

    let home = HomeController()
    let browse = BrowseController()
    let bag = BagController()
    let settings = SettingsController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.viewControllers = [home, browse, bag, settings]
        self.selectedIndex = 0

        self.tabBar.barTintColor = Colors.pink
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = Colors.darkPink
        self.tabBar.tintColor = Colors.darkGrey

        home.tabBarItem = homeTab
        browse.tabBarItem = browseTab
        bag.tabBarItem = bagTab
        settings.tabBarItem = settingsTab
    }
```

The label works fine, but my problem begins when the app is launched. The home screen, which is the root controller of the `UITabBarController` seems to ignore these auto-layout constraints of the `UILabel`. Obviously, in every screen, the text of the label is set in `viewDidLoad()`.

Picture of the issue (look to the top of the screen):
[image: issue]

The constraints seem to work when I navigate to another page:
[image: different screen working]

Then, when I navigate back to the first screen, it works now:
[image: original screen working]

If anyone could help me figure this issue out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: have you checked if the title is constrained to the safe area?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a minimal project, tested on iPhone 11 Pro Max because it's the one you're using in the screenshot, and it seems to be working just like you want:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        $0.textAlignment = .center
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    }
}

class MainTabController: UITabBarController {

    let home = ViewControllerA()
    let browse = ViewControllerB()
    let bag = ViewControllerC()
    let settings = ViewControllerD()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewControllers = [home, browse, bag, settings]
        selectedIndex = 0
        home.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        browse.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Browse", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        bag.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Bag", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        settings.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Settings", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
    }
}

class ViewControllerA: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.text = "Home"
    }
}

// ...
```

I'm wondering how do you set the root view controller of your app window, because that might be the issue here.

You're using the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` to constrain your view on the top so it will look fine on any devices (because you already have your height set to 50).

With that being said, if you want to have a title on the top of all your tab screens, I would say that using a base class and positioning the label by yourself at the top is definitely not the best approach, and in fact I would not recommend you to do so.

The reason is, what you're trying to do is exactly the role of a **Navigation Bar**.

If you want to have the navigation bar match the style of your screen to make it look just the same as your screenshot, it's pretty easy and you could simply change the background color of the navigation bar to transparent for example.

There would be no need for a base class, you can simply set the title property of your view controller, and more importantly you would get all the title animations for free!